# What does Forms.Control.Handle return in Mono Winforms on Mac OS?

Tags: winforms, macos, mono

What value does Form.Handle return in Mono Winforms on Macos?

Is it the Address of an NSView? or just a unique identifier of some kind?

There is no information in the mono documentation for System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle.

**Edit:**

Finally, I found this change log:

http://repo.or.cz/w/mcs.git/blob/4b050bb87f12c0ba443ec2a81a58d0ec43b15196?f=class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ChangeLog

which reads:

> - XplatUICarbon.cs:  ... subclass handler for com.novell.mwfview subclassing HIView.

So finally, it appears that Control.Handle returns an `HIViewRef`. So I'll have to use Carbon/AGL instead of Cocoa/NSOpengL so that I can pass the viewref to `aglSetHIViewRef()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal details can be found in the [XplatUICarbon.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/XplatUICarbon.cs) file. Apparently the handle is whatever is returned by a call to `HIObjectCreate`, see [line 1004](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/XplatUICarbon.cs#L1004). It's set into the `hwnd` on [line 1029](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/XplatUICarbon.cs#L1029) (cf. [Hwnd.cs line 443](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/Hwnd.cs#L443))